# how i can solve TyperError: matriz_ady() missing 1 required positional argument: "x"

Tags: python, function, variables, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I'm sorry if my coding is awful, but I'm new at coding and I need some help with this error: TyperError: matriz_ady() missing 1 required positional argument: "x".

It's a graph problem where I have to create a menu with the following option:

1. parameters: request by the keyboard the number of nodes (mínimum 6) and then I need to request the neighbors with their respective weight.

And this is what I have:

def crear_menu():

```
menu = int(input("Elija una opción \n 1.Crear parámetros \n 2.Aplicar Dijkstra \n 3.Aplicar Kruskal \n 4.Salir"))

while(menu != 4):
    
    if menu == 1:
        
        min_nodos()
        
    elif menu == 2:
        print("hola2")
        
    elif menu == 3:
        print("hola3")
        
    else:
        print("Escoja una opción válida")
```

def matriz_ady(x):

```
libro = openpyxl.Workbook()
pagina = libro.active
pagina.title = "matriz_adyacencia"
lista_nodos = []
i = 0


while(i < x):
    
    num = i+1
    nodo = input("Nombre de nodo" + num + ":")
    
    if nodo not in lista_nodos:
        lista_nodos.append(nodo)
        pagina.cell(row = i+2, column = 1, value = nodo)
        pagina.cell(row = 1, column = i+2, value = nodo)
        i = i+1
        
    else:
        print("Ingresar otro nodo:")


for j in range(0, len(lista_nodos)):
    
    nodo = lista_nodos[j]
    lista_vecinos = []
    conta = 0
    
    while(conta < x):
    
        conta2 = conta+1
        vecino = input("ingresar vecino" + conta2 + ":")
        
        if vecino not in lista_vecinos:
            for k in range(len(lista_nodos)):
                if lista_nodos[k] == vecino:
                    peso = int(input("Ingresar peso entre" + nodo + "y" + vecino + ":"))
                    lista_vecinos.append(vecino)
                    pagina.cell(row = i+2, column = k+2, value = peso)
                    conta = conta+1
                    
                else:
                    print("Este vecino ya está, ingresar otro")
                    
    libro.save("matriz_adyacencia.xlsx")
```

def min_nodos():

```
x = int(input("Elije la cantidad de nodos (mínimo 6):"))

while(x < 6):
    
    x= int(input("Error, elija mínimo 6: "))
    
return matriz_ady()
```

crear_menu()
min_nodos(x)
matriz_ady(x)

It would be very helpful if you can help me or know some page - video explaining what I have to learn.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The source if the error is this line `return matriz_ady()`. Maybe you want to do `return matriz_ady(x)`

Comment: thanks! that solve the problem. I didn't saw it.